# Select one specific date input control Jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

Can anyone assist me. I am using iReport 5.0. and Postgres.

I have Start Date and End Date as input controls, however I would like to give the user the option to either select Appointment Start Date or Visit Start date and end date respectively.

How can I achieve this without creating 4 input controls: Appointment Start, End Date, Visit Start, End Date. User must just choose to use either one of the two.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just set one Start Date and End Date, plus a dropdown with "Event type"? E.g. with *Appointment* and *Visit* in the list. If you need to add more later on, this approach could simplify.